# Can I change the starting price of my asset on Lobstr?

Tags: assets

So I set the price of my asset to 1 XLM and it is now Live on Lobstr. I tested it and bought a few for 1XLM per asset. Now I want to change the price to a lower figure - like 0,04 XLM.

I tried to build a new transaction (manage buy offer) and set the price to 0,04. But it doesn’t reflect the new price on Lobstr. Is there a refresh period or is it simply not possible to change the asset price again?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I set the price of my asset to 1XLM"? Can you post a link to your asset?